# How to fix C# compile when it haven't any error?

Tags: c#, compilation

I wrote an application with C#, and finally i changed Target Framework to .Net Framwork 3.5 , I had problem with this Target and i re changed it to .Net Framwork 4.5 but my application even didn't run, I used Rebuild Solution for solve it, but my application didn't run and after 15 seconds compile will stop without any error

what is wrong? how can fix it? please help me

EDIT:

Not that: when i changed it to .net framework 3.5 it get me this exception: the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. c#

but i changed it to .Net Framework 4.5 and I haven't any error and just app don't run

EDIT 2:

Problem Solved with make new project and copy all data to that

Comment: Can you please share some screenshots of the error? Or post the error that you are getting?

Comment: It don't get me any error but when i changed it to .net framework 3.5 it get me this error: the 'microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. c#

Answer (score 0):

The error which you have posted shows that the ACE engine is not configured on your system. You need to download 
**[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)** it and install it on your system to get it working.

Also note that there are two version available on the provided link x64 and x86.  x86 applications can use x86 version and x64 applications can use x64 version.